# How are people supposed to watch Naruto legally if they live outside America?when it's only licensed in Canada and US on crunchyroll

Tags: naruto

I'm curious , I saw online that Naruto can only be watched on Crunchyroll in Canada and the US

Comment: Buy the DVD/BD? Find the alternatives from [this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/923/2516)? Where are you currently located?

Comment: Thanks for responding Aki Tanaka , I'm located in Belgium.

Comment: You're not necessarily "supposed" to be able to do so.  Sometimes you just can't legally get things, and no one's under any obligation to provide you a legal avenue. That said, maybe there's a way that works for Belgium, I don't know.

Comment: @kaan I live in the netherlands but as long as I know there isn't really a legal way...

Comment: At least in the US, Naruto is also on Netflix, and Adult Swim on TV. Not sure about in other countries

Answer (score -1):

So I live in Australia, and I watch *Naruto* for at least 24 hours a month. If you want really good quality, then watch it on AnimeLab. If you don't want ads, then don't use the mobile AnimeLab.

Even though these really help you, the anime community gets affected if you don't buy official merchandise and DVDs, or watch it on official streaming websites, the anime production company will get shut down, meaning they won't produce more seasons, and no one wants that ;)

Comment: Take note that AnimeLab is currently only available on Australia and New Zealand, while the OP was living in Belgium from the comment. (Also, this community doesn't condone piracy, so questionable/illegal streaming sites are prohibited here)